# How to fetch multiple img tags from html using php?

Tags: php, html

```
<strong><a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/therevsteve/5152424274/sizes/l/">
<img src="http://www.brightknowledge.org/knowledge-bank/teaching/teaching-in-private-  schools/@@images/77cbbd71-bbf5-4fb6-a017-cc61016b6f60.jpeg" alt="Teaching in private schools" class="image-right" title="Photo by Steve Day" /></a>
There are big differences between teaching in independent and state schools. Find out about the most important ones here.</strong><img src="http://www.brightknowledge.org/++resource++brightside.theme.images/badge.png" />
```

Here is my HTML.I can able to fetch img tags one by one.There is multiple img tags in the HTML.How can I fetch these img tags using PHP?

Comment: you are fetching these tags from ?

Comment: Do you mean you want to get all img tags out of the DOM with php?

Answer (score 0):

You can query all img nodes by using XPath.

[The DOMXPath class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php)
There a good samples at the bottom of that page.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with this

```
preg_match_all('/<img[^>]+>/i',$html, $allTags); 

print_r($allTags);
```